# Is there any place to download Apple Configurator 1.3?

Tags: mobile-device-management, apple-configurator

I would like to use Apple Configurator for our Store iPads, but I can't upgrade my iMac to 10.8 (min. Requirement for AC 1.4) right now.

Where can I get 1.3 or any other version that I could install on 10.7.5?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/8ldzpp9ajy7y82k/Apple%20Configurator%201.2.1.zip

I found it on https://jamfnation.jamfsoftware.com

Hope it will work.

Comment: The usual warnings regarding downloading Apple software from non-apple sources applies. Proceed with care.

Comment: Link not found... :-(

Answer (score 0):

Look on reddit, you can find some old apple configurator download links. Here is [Apple Configurator 2.2 beta 3 DMG](https://mega.nz/#!r0AhhAjL!FdxeVeYqqegW4KUZTKo1MFpt76e5BJztXVqN0HtFEFg). Apparently, CNET hosts some apple configurator downloads too  https://download.cnet.com/archive/3000-2651_4-12222355.html.

Comment: Careful with CNET, they're known for sometimes having no-so-clean copies.